# Trying to load and execute a js file, which returns a flash image , using $.getScript() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have a script which returns a flash file.Previously the flash file returned by the js was done in the following manner

```
<div id="verisign-logo">
     <script src=verisign-logo-url></script>
</div>
```

This displayed a flash image in the div.

Now I am trying to load and execute a javascript file in the following manner

```
<div id="verisign-logo">
   <script>
        $.getScript( verisign-logo-url, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
            console.log( textStatus ); // Success
            console.log( jqxhr.responseText ); // 200
            console.log( data);
            console.log( "Load was performed." );
            });
  </script>
</div>
```

The request to the external server is made however the flash file is not being displayed. What exactly am I missing? Also I would like to know how to display the retrieved script.

Comment: Anything that appears on the console? Besides the ones you wrote?

Comment: I take it firstly that "verisign-logo-url" is a real URL you've just changed to display here? Also getScript is only designed to load and execute JavaScript. What kind-of Flash file are you requesting? You should be able to use a normal get and deal with it by either writing it to the page or parsing it.